# Employee name auto-complete on card scan

Tags: vba, excel, autocomplete

Im currently running an employee name substitution on card scan.
Overall the code takes the entry trough the gun scan, "scan" trough the hidden reference sheet to find a match and then input the actual complete name.

I had to implement that feature to my code so that names are always written the same (for futur data treatment purpose).

If y'all have some tip, hint or other proposition to optimise the code.
One of my goal would be for it to auto-fill with any entry (right now mostly working with operator numbers) or to suggest entries based on what's written in real time in a scrolling menu (if it's not too much).

Here's my codes :

```
Sub Workbook_sheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C5:C8")) Is Nothing Then 'If change in "no.employé" cells

Call Employe ' Call name standardization macro

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Employe()
' Standardization of the operator name macro
' The code automaticly enters the employee names by is number entry
' Therefore permits employee to scan their pass and get their full names automaticly

Dim ash As Worksheet
Set ash = ActiveSheet ' Identify active sheet 
Dim positionInitCaseNom1enY As Long: positionInitCaseNom1enY = 5 'First "Name" cell row position
Dim positionCaseNomEnX As Long: positionCaseNomEnX = 3           '"Name" cells culumn position
Dim k As long: k = positionInitCaseNom1enY                    ' Counter incrément position
Dim no As Variant  ' Value of name cell (changes every loop)
Dim i As Integer   ' Row integer

    For i = 0 To 3
    k = k + i       ' Up a row (first 0)
    no = ash.Cells(k, positionCaseNomEnX).Value ' Gives "no" the current "Name" cell value
    
        If no <> "" Then   ' Vérify if theres something in "Name" cell
        Dim nos As String  
        nos = CStr(no)     ' no to string (now nos)
        Dim valeurnorm As Range
        Set valeurnorm = Sheets("Liste Employé").Range("A2:A200").Find(nos)
        ' Looking for a match in name reference sheet
        
            If valeurnorm Is Nothing Then ' If no match found
                If MsgBox("Entrer un numéro d'employé valide" & vbNewLine & "Le numéro d'employé entrée est le suivant: " & nos, 5 + vbCritical, "Erreur") = vbRetry Then
                ' Msgbox that the employee entered a false number and to retry

                    ash.Cells(k, positionCaseNomEnX).Value = "" ' Clear old number
                    ash.Cells(k, positionCaseNomEnX).Select     ' Reselect cases

                End If
            Else ' If name is in the reference sheet

                ash.Cells(k, positionCaseNomEnX).Value = valeurnorm ' Change the value of the entry for the complete name
            End If
            
        End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Sorry for all of the typos, i need to translate everything and my written english is kinda s***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`positionInitCaseNom1enY` and `positionCaseNomEnX` should be declared as `Const` or in an `Enum` because they are default values that never change.

```
Const positionInitCaseNom1enY As Long = 5
Const positionCaseNomEnX As Long = 3
```

Do to implicit conversion `no` does not need to be cast to a String.  The compiler automatically does it for you.

```
Dim nos As String  
nos = CStr(no)     ' no to string (now nos)
```

Use dynamic ranges whenever possible.

```
Set valeurnorm = Sheets("Liste Employé").Range("A2:A200").Find(nos)
```

Assuming the name list is the only thing in column A, you should dynamically size you range to fit the data like this:

> ```
> With Sheets("Liste Employé")
>     Set valeurnorm = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Find(nos)
> End With
> ```

[image: Employee Names]

Using **Dynamic Named Ranges** helps to give your code identity.  And that is what we want to do as developers.  If you have to comeback a year from now, you may not know what `StandarValues` represent but you will immediately understand what `EmployeeNames` are.

> Set employeeNames= Sheets("Liste Employé").Range("EmployeeNames").Find(nos)

Alerts are necessary but having to click a `MsgBox()` can get irritating.  I would prefer that:

> If .Find("Another Solution") is Not Nothing Then Call
> Use(.Find("Another Solution"))

### Solution 1: Use Conditional Formatting

[How To Highlight Cells If Not In Another Column In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3499-excel-highlight-cells-not-in-list.html)

### Solution 2: Use an ActiveX Combobox

Setup
• Insert a hidden ComboBox on each Worksheet that needs the name validation
• Give it a meaning full name
• Set it's ListFillRange a **Dynamic Named Range** of employee names

[image: ComboBox ListFillRange]

When a cell in the validation range is selected use the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange()`
• Move the ComboBox over the Activecell
• REsize the ComboBox to fit the ActiveCell
• Set the `ComboBox.LinkedCell = ActiveCell`
• Set focus to the ComboBox

When the user selects a cell in the
• Hide the ComboBox
• Set the `ComboBox.LinkedCell = Nothing`

[image: Combo ValidationList]

> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
>     AdjustEmployeeNameComboBox Sh, Target
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub AdjustEmployeeNameComboBox(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
>     Dim hasEmployeeRange As Boolean
>     On Error Resume Next
>     
>     Dim EmployeeNameComboBox As OLEObject
>     Set EmployeeNameComboBox = Sh.OLEObjects("EmployeeNameComboBox")
>     hasEmployeeRange = Err.Number = 0
>     On Error GoTo 0
>
>     If Not hasEmployeeRange Then Exit Sub
>     
>     Dim isEmployeeRangeSelected As Boolean
>     isEmployeeRangeSelected = Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C5:C8")) Is Nothing
>     
>     With EmployeeNameComboBox
>         .LinkedCell = ""
>         .Visible = isEmployeeRangeSelected
>     End With
>     
>     If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
>     
>     If isEmployeeRangeSelected Then
>         With EmployeeNameComboBox
>             .LinkedCell = Target.Address
>             .Top = Target.Top
>             .Left = Target.Left
>             .Height = Target.Height
>             .Width = Target.Width
>             .Activate
>         End With
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Ugh..kinda nasty but it works.

Solution 3: Almost the Same as 2

Use the same setup as Solution2 but use a Cell Style to indicate that it is an Employee Name Validation Range.  The advantage of this is that you could have the validation anywhere on the Worksheet without having to update your code.

For this solution you will need to change

> isEmployeeRangeSelected = Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C5:C8")) Is Nothing

to this

> isEmployeeRangeSelected = Target.Style = "Cell Style Name goes Here"

Comment: Add parenthesis around the comparison before assignment to the variable to explicitly indicate the order of operation. That way it is evident that the comparison comes first, then the assignment: `isEmployeeRangeSelected = (Target.Style = "Cell Style Name goes Here")`. This makes it less confusing since VBA uses `=` for both comparison and assignment.

Comment: Good point @IvenBach.  Thanks

Comment: @TinMan as of right now, because lack of time, il stick to correcting the existing with your your review, but il sure experiment with your proposition later! Thx!

Comment: @PatatesPilées Thanks for accepting my answer.